# Creating an NSDate from an API's value

Tags: objective-c, date, nsdate, foundation

I have a (Ruby on Rails site's) API which returns JSON data with datetimes formatted like this:

```
2011-01-21T18:05:41Z
```

I have this in an NSString, and I want to make an NSDate of it. How can I do this?

Comment: Date format patterns here: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];`

NSDate *theDate =  [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2011-01-21T18:05:41Z"];